# What is the rationale for using Web Components in web apps?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web, web-component

Google at I/O 2013 introduced support for [Web Components](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/explainer/index.html). It allows us to make reusable HTML modules for inserting into web pages. But today we can embed those widgets on client side using `<iframe>`-s, hidden `<div>`-s, AJAX, JavaScript templates like EJS or mustache.js, or even XSLT. We can even put them in sandboxes using `<iframe sandbox>`, Google Caja or Microsoft Web Sandbox. What is so special in Web Components so that we should use it?

Comment: Doesn't the videos from google io answer you question? Take a look at https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/318907648 and https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/324149970

Comment: You should carefully read that draft and think about what you'd have to do to implement all those features.

Comment: I've read it, but for me using all those `<decorator id="fade-to-white"><template><content></content></template></decorator><element extends="button" name="x-fancybutton"></element><button is="x-fancybutton"></button>` is too much bloat. Don't we already have simpler solutions?

Comment: The ability to control the application of decorators via ordinary CSS semantics seems extremely powerful.